# How can I view a YouTube playlist's full name?

Tags: ios, youtube

In the YouTube iOS app, a playlist's name will be truncated if it's too log to fit on a single line. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to view the playlist's full title if it's been shortened.

**Is it possible to view a playlist's full name if it's been auto-shortened?**

[image: truncated YouTube playlist name]

Comment: Is it a latest version of YouTube app?

Comment: @AndreyKuznetsov Yes. Version 12.21.7 on an iPhone 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hit the Share button that looks like a right-pointing arrow
2. Choose "Twitter" from the list

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a twitter account you can tap `Share -> Twitter` to see full name of playlist.